# trouble passing data between tabs

Tags: xcode4.2, ios5

I am writing a program which passes data between tabs. Fill a UITextField in the 1st tab, select the 2nd tab and see it displayed.

The data to be passed is stored in a var in the 2nd tab in the viewWillDisappear method of the 1st view. It is retrieved in the viewWillAppear method of the 2nd View.

But there seems to be a race condition. In the debugger I see the viewWillAppear is invoked BEFORE viewWillDisappear. The sequence is: view2.viewWillAppear -> view1.viewWillDisappear.

Am I using the correct methods?

I am writing for iOS5 target in Xcode 4.2.1. This version no longer creates a MainWindo.xib, so I am bit confused as to how to wire the AppDelgate to the Tab Bar Controllers. Can anyone tell me how to access the TabBar Controllers in XCode 4.2.1. ?

I'm happy to clarify/provide code. Trying to keep this post brief.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your tab bar implementation is it is custom. or as a workaround You can use  Singleton class (like in app delegate or your own custom Singleton. Set your value in Singleton retrieve in any class.